# How to run an Android App in the background

Tags: android

We have an existing android app that no longer works on new devices running android 33.

The app has no UI, it currently keeps calling our server to check for new data from a background service, when that data is seen it displays and sounds a notification, that notification then opens up our webapp in chrome.

From what I can see it seems that background services are no longer always running, a foreground service leaves something running that the user can close, workmanager would have been ideal but a minimum of 15 mins is too high, we really need it to run every few seconds. Can anyone suggest what to look at?

FYI, the devices devices running the app runs on a private network and are provided to users solely for this purpose.

Comment: "it currently keeps calling our server to check for new data from a background service" -- background services have not worked in several years. "we really need it to run every few seconds" -- since that is very hard on the battery, Android goes way out of its way to prevent people from doing that, except via a (foreground) service, so users are in control over their devices.

Comment: Yep, its an old app that we have had to start refreshing hardware for and hence we found it no longer works.  We could get away with doing it less frequent, but 15mins for the workmanager is too long, basically a notification means a system fault has been discovered and needs to be looked at asap.

Comment: "basically a notification means a system fault has been discovered and needs to be looked at asap" -- that makes no sense, sorry. "we have had to start refreshing hardware for" -- modify your custom build of the Android OS to leave your app alone, despite it running in the background. For example, rather than it being an app, it could be a regular Linux daemon.

Comment: When the app creates a notification it means that the user has to do something as soon as possible a potential 15 minute delay is just too long.

Comment: And as I typed that I just realised I've missed an obvious solution, just schedule another task with a delay at the end of the task.